# how to emit a signal from a non_GUI class and from a non-GUI thread which we can detect in main GUI class

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qthread

I want to Show an Image from other class into QLabel but to inform the GUI that a new Frame is available. I need to emit a Signal from a non_GUI class and from a non-GUI thread.

Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Did you look at the [`QThread`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#details) documentation? There is an example there that emits a signal from a different thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `signal` can be emitted from any class object which inherits `QObject`. And that `signal` can be caught in any `slot` provided the signatures are compatible. You can just inherit `QObject` by your *non-GUI* class. Then connect the `signal-slot` for a specific object.  But since multi-threading is involved, you should be careful about any **shared** data access. Also know properly about [connection types](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots) and [thread affinity](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html)